# fitting the python plot with exponential function

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my python plot with an exponential function. I have attached the code here. Any inputs is highly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=[0.21, 0.43, 0.50, 0.65, 0.86, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0]
y=[43, 33, 30, 24, 18, 16, 14, 13, 14, 13, 13]
yerr= [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
xerr=[0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01, 0.01,0.01,0.01]
plt.ylim (0,60)
plt.xlabel ('Thickness (d) [mm]')
plt.ylabel ('Counts')
def exponenial_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, x, y, p0=(1, 1e-6, 1))
yy = exponenial_func(x, *popt)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x, yy)
#plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr,xerr=xerr, fmt= '.')
plt.show()
```

I always get an error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manisha/Desktop/Moessbauer effect/countsvsd.py", line 16, in <module>
    yy = exponenial_func(x, *popt)
  File "/home/manisha/Desktop/Moessbauer effect/countsvsd.py", line 14, in exponenial_func
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Since I am a new programmer I don't know what it means. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the way you are trying to define `yy`; you can't call your function on the *list* `x`. Instead, call it on each individual item in `x`, for instance, in a list iteration like this:

```
yy = [exponenial_func(i, *popt) for i in x]
```

Then, everything else in your code works fine:
[image: exponential]

**[EDIT]**: to extrapolate the zero in your exponential function (as per your comment), you can do this:

```
xx = x.copy()    
yy = [exponenial_func(i, *popt) for i in [0]+xx]
plt.plot(x,y,'o',[0]+xx,yy)
```

Or, to just see the value, do this:

```
exponenial_func(0, *popt)
```

Comment: Hi Sacul, Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Is there a way to extrapolate the fit to x=0?

Answer (score 0):

While the answer of @sacul works, it does not tell you yet what is happening.

if you have a `list`, you can append copies of this `list` to itself by multiplication.

```
my_list = [1, 2]
print(my_list * 2) #[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

So, when you try to multiply the `list` with a `float`, it will become undefined what the behaviour of the copying should be, and an `Exception` is thrown.

```
print(my_list * 1.5) #TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Trying to do so with a floating point object, will instead be caught before evaluation time and raise the following error:

```
a = 1.5
print(my_list*a) #TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So there are multiple solutions to your problem. You can feed the individual items in your `list` to the function one by one, like in the answer provided by @sacul, or convert your container to a type which will yield array behaviour like you expected it to:

```
def exponenial_func(x, a, b, c):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        x = np.array(x)
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c
```